# flex/bison accepts opening brace when missing

Tags: compiler-construction, bison, flex-lexer, yacc

I am working on flex/bison.

The problem is when I input `if(a<b)}` it accepts it but there is an opening brace missing.

Below is the grammer:

```
S : ST { printf("\nCORRECT INPUT\n"); exit(0); }

ST : IF  OB Expr1 CB | IF OB Expr1 CB OCB CCB 

Expr1 : ID EQ ID
    | ID EQ NUM
    | NUM EQ NUM
    | NUM EQ ID
    | ID NE ID
    | ID NE NUM
    | NUM NE NUM
    | NUM NE ID
    | ID LT ID
    | ID LT NUM
    | NUM LT NUM
    | NUM LT ID
    | ID GT ID
    | ID GT NUM
    | NUM GT NUM
    | NUM GT ID
    | ID LE ID
    | ID LE NUM
    | NUM LE NUM
    | NUM LE ID
    | ID GE ID
    | ID GE NUM
    | NUM GE NUM
    | NUM GE ID
```

Comment: "(" {return OB;}
")" {return CB;}
"{" {return OCB;}
"}" {return CCB;}

Comment: You should edit your post, and add helpful information to it and not in comments.

Comment: By the way, that grammar desperately needs to be refactored. Inserting four productions for every operator is unreadable and unscalable. Consider `Term: ID | NUM`, which you will later want to change to something more like `Term: ID | NUM | '(' Expr ')'`

Comment: Thank you, that's a very good suggestion :)

Comment: BTW, do you have any solution of the above mentioned problem?

Answer (score 2):

You decide the input is acceptable and then call `exit(0)` from the reduction action for `S -> ST`. That reduction can happen before the parser notices that it is not at the end of input. (This is a parse table optimisation implemented by most LALR parser generators.)

So the parser recognises `if(a<b)`; observes that it cannot shift `}`; observes that it can reduce that to `ST` and then to  `S`; and never has the chance to throw a syntax error because your reduction action immediately claims success.

It is almost never a good idea to exit a parse in a reduction action, and most certainly not with an explicit return or call to `exit`. If you detect an error in a reduction action, you can cause the parse to fail by using the `YYABORT` macro.

There is also a `YYACCEPT` macro which causes me immediate success but it will often get you into exactly the same problem as you are experiencing here. (But it will at least cleanly terminate the parse, releasing whatever resources are being used by the parser and lexical scanner.)

It is almost always best to just let the parse continue until it either detects success or detects an error. You can tell that the parse succeeded because `yyparse` will return 0 for success.

Comment: I remove the exit thing from start rule and now at input: if(a<b)} it fist shows correct input and then prints error.

Comment: @danyal: Yes, it prints the message when it performs the reduction. Please read the answer again.